# ASP.NET Linq to sql multiple foreign keys to primary key different table

Tags: asp.net, sql, linq

I have a table called `claims` which has an id called `currencyId` of datatype `INT`.

Then also a table called `tblCurrency` with primary ID of `currencyId`.

And then had an association which was fine. Then in Linq I could use

```
    <%# ((claim)Container.DataItem).currency.value %>
```

But now I have to add another `INT` column to `tblClaims` called `finalCurrencyID` which I also want an association with to `tblCurrency`.

Just wondering how I could achieve this, so at the moment `((claim)Container.DataItem).currency.value` is linking up `claim.currencyId` to `tblCurrency.currencyID` and getting `tblCurrency.value`.

But how could I make it more flexible so I can determine which `currencyID` from `tblClaims` to call?

Comment: Think about restructuring your question.  This is extremely confusing.  You have to paint a better picture of what is going on.  What do you mean by '...can determine which currencyID from tblClaims to call'?  And are we to assume you are using a GridView?  How about providing a diagram showing what your data structure looks like or what you would like it to look like.  Are you saying that your tblClaims will have two references to tblCurrency - currencyID AND finalCurrencyID?  Are you asking how to use the aforementioned fields to query data from tblCurrency using a LINQ statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I read the right, I think you are looking for this:

```
<%# ((claim)Container.DataItem).finalCurrency.value %>
```

Assuming, of course, that you've wired up `claim` to have a L2S FK to `finalCurrency`.